# Rails3 Facebook-esque localized language picklist

Tags: localization, ruby-on-rails-3

Other than copying Facebook's SELECT and OPTION elements, is there a Rails-native way of generating a Facebook-esque, localized-language select list?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "Rails-native" you mean "provided by Rails core," then no. However, you can access a list of locales *your app provides translations for* via `I18n.available_locales`. If one of the values of your locale is a localized version of the name of the language, you can use it to build a select:

```
# as a helper
def available_locales
  I18n.available_locales.map{ |l| [t('name', :locale => l), l] }
end

# in a view
= select_tag :language, options_for_select(available_locales, I18n.locale.to_sym)
```

If you want something that will build the list for you, you might check out a Gem or plugin, such as [localized_language_select](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/localized_language_select).